# Converting Google Sheet to JSON format while rows are vertical

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, json

I am trying to convert the Google Sheets into JSON format using Google App Script.
It worked but I am not getting the right format and I am little struck.

My sheet looks something like this in the image

[image: google sheets]

Then I am running the Google Script  code. This is my code.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nse = sheet.getSheetByName("email-preview");
  var data = [];
  var rlen = nse.getLastRow();  /*how many rows are there? */
  var clen = nse.getLastColumn();
  var rows = nse.getRange(1, 1, rlen, clen).getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var datarow = rows[i];
    var record = "";
    for(var j=0;j<35;j++){
      record[rows[0][j]]=datarow[j]; 
    }
    data.push(record); 
  }

  console.log(data);
  var result=JSON.stringify(data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I am getting the output something like this,

```
   [ { field1: 1000 },
      { field2: 2000 },
      { field3: 3000 },
      { field4: 4000 },
      { field5: 5000 },
      { field6: 6000 },
      { field7: 7000 },
      { field8: 800 },
      { field9: 9000 },
      { field10: 1 },
      { field11: 2 },
      { field12: 3 },
      { field13: 4 },
      { field14: 5 },
      { field15: 6 },
      { field16: 7 },
      { field17: 8 },
      { field18: 9 },
      { field19: 10 },
      { field20: 11 },
      { field21: 12 },
      { field22: 13 },
      { field23: 14 },
      { field24: 15 },
      { field25: 16 } ]
```

Expected Output:

```
    [ { field1: 1000,
      field2: 2000, 
      field3: 3000,
      field4: 4000,
      field5: 5000,
      field6: 6000,
      field7: 7000,
       field8: 800,
       field9: 9000,
       field10: 1,
       field11: 2,
       field12: 3,
       field13: 4,
       field14: 5,
       field15: 6,
       field16: 7,
       field17: 8,
       field18: 9,
       field19: 10,
       field20: 11,
       field21: 12,
       field22: 13,
       field23: 14,
       field24: 15,
       field25: 16 } ]
```

Can anyone let me know how to fix it, and also make the results dynamic in case I add a new field?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Interesting problem. Just for the record, your "Expected Output" is not valid JSON (try it in [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)). Valid JSON would look like this "[{"field1": 1000, "field2": 2000, "field3": 3000,"... Is this deliberate? On a tangent, have you tried any other code than in your question?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a substitute for code that makes "JSON "properly, but it is a quick-and-dirty approach that does create valid JSON.

- Enter this formula in cell in row1.
  `=ArrayFormula(concatenate("[{", join(", "&char(10), char(34)&B1:B25&char(34)&char(58)&char(32)&C1:C25), "}]"))`
- Then Copy, Paste special, Values only

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nse = sheet.getSheetByName("email-preview");
  
  var rlen = nse.getLastRow();  /*how many rows are there? */
  var clen = nse.getLastColumn();

  // ignore Column A in getting the Range
  var range =  nse.getRange(1, 2, rlen, clen-1)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the Range is: "+nse.getRange(1, 2, rlen, clen-1).getA1Notation())
  
  // get the values and then  
  // establish arrays for the fields and values
  var rows = range.getValues(); 
  var fields  = rows.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  //Logger.log(fields) // DEBUG
  var values  = rows.map(function(e){return e[1]})
  //Logger.log(values) // DEBUG

  //establish variables for an array and object
  var data = []
  var obj = {}

  //Loop through the rows and build the object
  for (var i = 0; i<rlen;i++){
    // test if this is a blank row
    //assign object field to value
    if(fields[i]!='') obj[fields[i]] = values[i];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i = "+i+" "+fields[i]+' '+values[i])
  }

  // Logger.log(obj) // DEBUG
  
  // the object is complete
  // now push the object onto the array
  data.push(obj)
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data)) // DEBUG
  
  var result=JSON.stringify(data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

---

The fields and values are in adjacent columns in the Spreadsheet. So there's no need to look at headings or header rows. On each row there is a field and value. So if the field value is not blank, then the object field equals the adjacent value.  A simple `FOR` loop enables the code to move through each row of data.

`if(fields[i]!='') obj[fields[i]] = values[i];`

Once the object is completed, it is pushed onto an array:
`myarray.push(obj)`

The result of `JSON.stringify(data)` is:

> [
> {
> "field1":1000,
> "field2":2000,
> "field3":3000,
> "field4":4000,
> "field5":5000,
> "field6":6000,
> "field7":7000,
> "field8":800,
> "field9":9000,
> "field10":1,
> "field11":2,
> "field12":3,
> "field13":4,
> "field14":5,
> "field15":6,
> "field16":7,
> "field17":8,
> "field18":9,
> "field19":10,
> "field20":11,
> "field21":12,
> "field22":13,
> "field23":14,
> "field24":15,
> "field25":16
> }
> ]